# California Exempt Employment Minimum Pay not being met

Tags: california, labor-law

I am currently working full time as an exempt employee in California for a company of over 25 people.

I have read that due to the California minimum wage increase to $14, I am supposed to be paid a minimum of $58,240 (https://www.worklawyers.com/exempt-employee-salary-california/). I am currently not being paid this much as of January 1, 2021.

Am I owed an increase in salary? If so, am I also owed back pay for the days worked in 2021 so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't get an answer for this here, but was successful with HR, so I will post the information here (for future viewers).

The claims in the original question are correct and I have been retroactively compensated with the increase back to January 1st of this year.